# Pass selected value to function using jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, menu

I am a new jquery/js user trying to pass an argument from a selector to a function.  Here is some of the code:

```
// function to select data
var data = [
    {val: 10, year: 1990}, {val: 20, year: 1991}
]
var year_data = []
function select_year_data(y) {
    year_data = data.filter(function(d) {return d.year==y})
}
```

// Selector

```
<select name="Year" id = "year_menu" style="width: 230px; position: absolute; left: 400px; top: 50px">
<option value=1990>1990</option>
<option value=1991>1991</option>
</select>
```

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
<onchange>select_year_data($('#year_menu.val()')
```

But I know that isn't quite right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jquery change method can be used here [Change()](http://api.jquery.com/change)

```
$(function()
{
  $('#year_menu').change(function(){
      select_year_data($(this).val())
  });
});
```

Comment: Great solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

like this?

```
function select_year_data() {
    var y = $('#year_menu.val()';
    year_data = data.filter(function(d) {return d.year==y})
}
```

Comment: Looks awesome -- could you let me know how to initiate the event upon a change to the selector (ie, integrate the onclick portion)

Comment: the syntax for second line would be var y = $('#year_menu').val();

Comment: But how do I ensure that the function is re-exectured when I update the selector option?

Comment: I have added an answer with which does that. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use your function as  [$.onchange](http://api.jquery.com/onchange) 's callback then you will always have the data selected based on users selection on the variable `year_data`

```
function select_year_data() {
    var y = $(this).val();
    year_data = data.filter(function(d) {return d.year==y});
}
// call that func on change event
$('#year_menu').change(select_year_data);

// or straight forward one without another function
$('#year_menu').change(function(){
  var y = $(this).val();
  year_data = data.filter(function(d) {return d.year==y});
});
// assuming year_data and data is declared in global scope.
```